Parameter indentation in C in tree-sitter mode
I can't get c-ts-mode to indent function parameters properly. I want it to use "lineup indentation" if there is a parameter on the function identifier line and otherwise "one-step indentation". Here is what I mean with lineup indentation:
void fun_name(int foo, int bar,
              int baz,
              char *eh);

Here is what I mean with one-step indentation:
void fun_name(
    int foo, int bar,
    int baz,
    char *eh
);


I figured it out. Just add matching rules like these to your
treesitter indent style function:
  ((match nil "enumerator_list" nil 0 1) parent-bol c-ts-mode-indent-offset)
  ((match nil "enumerator_list" nil 2 nil) (nth-sibling 1) 0)

  ((match nil "parameter_list" nil 0 1) parent-bol c-ts-mode-indent-offset)
  ((match nil "parameter_list" nil 2 nil) (nth-sibling 1) 0)

  ((match nil "argument_list" nil 0 1) parent-bol c-ts-mode-indent-offset)
  ((match nil "argument_list" nil 2 nil) (nth-sibling 1) 0)

  ((match nil "initializer_list" nil 0 1) parent-bol c-ts-mode-indent-offset)
  ((match nil "initializer_list" nil 2 nil) (nth-sibling 1) 0)

  ((match nil "field_declaration_list" nil 0 1) parent-bol c-ts-mode-indent-offset)
  ((match nil "field_declaration_list" nil 2 nil) (nth-sibling 1) 0)

  ((match nil "parenthesized_expression" nil 0 1) parent-bol c-ts-mode-indent-offset)
  ((match nil "parenthesized_expression" nil 2 nil) (nth-sibling 1) 0)

So the first parameter is indented one level. But all subsequent
parameters are indented to the position of the first parameter
((nth-sibling 1)).
